# How to send and read a map object to nodejs API

Tags: node.js, angular

I am trying to send a map object from my angular front end to nodejs backend API but unable to parse and read the same at the backend.

Following is my API -

```
router.get('/updateRecords/:list', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('***' + req.params.list);
});
```

Following is how I am trying to send the object to it -

```
updateItems(list) {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/updateRecords/' + list)
    .pipe(
      catchError(err => this.handleError(err))
    );
  }
```

I am unable to read the object in my `updateRecords` API at the backend. The `console.log` above prints `Object object`.

If I tried to use `forEach` on the list object in `updateRecords`, it starts giving internal server error. Map object have key value pairs as I can print in console on the UI before sending.

Comment: Note: if you want to see the content of your object in the log, use multiple parameters like this `console.log('***', req.params.list);`, or else the concatenation with the string will call `toString` on the object, leading to `[Object object]` display

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you mean.

Comment: if you want to see your object content in your log, replace `console.log('***' + req.params.list);` by `console.log('***', req.params.list);` (`+` replaced by `,`)

Comment: Well, that makes sense but no impact on the output.

Comment: If that doesn't change the output, it means that your object was already converted to string, possibly before sending it, you can check this in your network tab, in the response

Comment: If the output says `Object Map Iterator`, what to deduce from that?

Comment: It probably means that you are trying to pass another object, but with the same method than previously. Using `'http://localhost:3000/updateRecords/' + list` won't work, you can't add an object directly as a concatenated URL parameter, or it will be converted to string as `[Object object]` (or `Object Map Iterator`, etc). You need to use for example the solution in Tony Ngo's answer, optionnally converting it to JSON first.